# W3C link checker: Status: 501 Protocol scheme 'tel' is not supported

Tags: html, validation, linkchecker

I'm trying to validate the links via https://validator.w3.org/checklink, but getting error

> `Status: 501 Protocol scheme 'tel' is not supported`

I tried to search on google and went through with many articles I don't find satisfying answers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This means that the validator has not been programmed to test `tel:` URLs in its process of checking links on a page. The testing would mean actually making a telephone call; and this is what you can do to test a link with a `tel:` URL: open the page in a browser that supports such links and activate the link.

Comment: Hi Jukka Thank you, Do we have any reference link to confirm the same